# How to write to a JSON file in the correct format

Tags: ruby, json, file

I am creating a hash in Ruby and want to write it to a JSON file, in the correct format.

Here is my code:

```
tempHash = {
    "key_a" => "val_a",
    "key_b" => "val_b"
}
fJson = File.open("public/temp.json","w")
fJson.write(tempHash)
fJson.close
```

And here is the contents of the resulting file:

```
key_aval_akey_bval_b
```

I'm using Sinatra (don't know what version) and Ruby v 1.8.7.

How can I write this to the file in the correct JSON format?

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684588/how-to-do-ruby-object-serialization-using-json

Comment: What you're doing is actually something I use a lot to document the JSON and YAML structures I use. I'll write a small piece of code to save the YAML/JSON to a file, then build same structures showing what the data should look like before and/or after dumping and reloading. So, though your code isn't working quite right, stick with this process as it makes life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Require the [JSON](http://flori.github.com/json/) library, and use `to_json`.

```
require 'json'

d = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
}

File.open('out.json', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(d.to_json)
end
```

Your temp.json file now looks like:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

Comment: Minor improvement: I suggest the block form: `File.open(...){ |f| f << h.to_json }`

Comment: `JSON.pretty_generate(tempHash)` is also rad http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate

Comment: Is there any version now which does not generate the memory overhead of building the string in memory first?  This is a larger memory fragmentation problem if the json is getting into the megabytes range. 10 years later somebody should have optimized it

Comment: This answer is now **well** out of date (for Ruby 1.8). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829359/1852005 for a much simpler solution using `File.write`.

Answer (score 110):

With formatting

```
require 'json'
tempHash = {
    "key_a" => "val_a",
    "key_b" => "val_b"
}
File.open("public/temp.json","w") do |f|
  f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(tempHash))
end
```

Output

```
{
    "key_a":"val_a",
    "key_b":"val_b"
}
```

Comment: I like the "a+" option. Doesn't clobber existing data.

Comment: @boulder_ruby appending may only make sense if the file format is JSONlines (one JSON object per line) and that hardly ever combines well with `pretty_generate`, unless the consumer of the output is a human. Even then, it's better to generate JSONlines and use something like `jq` to see the output.

Answer (score 23):

This question is for ruby 1.8 but it still comes on top when googling.

in ruby >= 1.9 you can use

```
File.write("public/temp.json",tempHash.to_json)
```

other than what mentioned in other answers, in ruby 1.8 you can also use one liner form

```
File.open("public/temp.json","w"){ |f| f.write tempHash.to_json }
```

Comment: Use `File.write("public/temp.json", JSON.pretty_generate(tempHash))` (as per other answers) to get pretty JSON formatting in the output.

Answer (score 3):

To make this work on Ubuntu Linux:

1. I installed the Ubuntu package ruby-json:

   ```
   apt-get install ruby-json
   ```
2. I wrote the script in `${HOME}/rubybin/jsonDEMO`
3. `$HOME/.bashrc` included:

   ```
   ${HOME}/rubybin:${PATH}
   ```

(On this occasion I also typed the above on the bash command line.)

Then it worked when I entered on the command line:

```
jsonDemo
```