# How to export json file by ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

I'd like to export JSON file like sample.json by ruby. (I'll upload the json.file to S3)

I expect the following way, however it needs to prepare json file before. Are there any way to export json file on ruby?

```
File.open("sample.json", "w") do |f|
   f.write(sample_data.to_json)
end
```

**sample.json**

```
{
  "asset_ids": [
    "this is id",
  ],
  "contract_url": "http://hoge.com/",
  "name_short": "Hoge",
  "name": "HogeHoge",
  "issuer": "Fuga",
  "description": "",
  "description_mime": "text/x-markdown; charset=UTF-8",
  "type": "Currency",
  "divisibility": 1,
  "link_to_website": false,
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with the way you are doing it?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507512/write-to-json-file-in-correct-format-ruby

Comment: Dear Gami
Thank you! I'll check it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple example (which is pretty much what you are doing):

```
hash = {:h => 1, :k => 2, :v => 3}
File.open("sample.json", "wb") { |file| file.puts JSON.pretty_generate(hash) }
```

I am using `JSON.pretty_generate` instead of `to_json` to format JSON output, else it would print everything in one line.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU, there is a task to both read the file containing json and to write it back (possible after some modifications.)

First of all, the code above is not valid json, the comma right before closing square bracket should be removed.

After the comma is removed and content is stored in the file `sample.json`:

```
▶ require 'json'
#⇒ true
▶ json = JSON.parse File.read '/tmp/a.json'
#⇒ {
#         "asset_ids" => [
#    [0] "this is id"
#  ],
#      "contract_url" => "http://hoge.com/",
#       "description" => "",
#  "description_mime" => "text/x-markdown; charset=UTF-8",
#      "divisibility" => 1,
#            "issuer" => "Fuga",
#   "link_to_website" => false,
#              "name" => "HogeHoge",
#        "name_short" => "Hoge",
#              "type" => "Currency",
#           "version" => "1.0"
# }
```

OK, we just got the content into ruby hash. To store it back:

```
▶ File.write 'sample.json', JSON.dump(json)
#⇒ 260
```

To store it in human readable pretty format:

```
▶ File.write 'sample.json', JSON.pretty_generate(json)
#⇒ 260
```