# Jquery - set textarea value with \r\n included

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to set a `textarea` value with a paragraph that's coming from a database.

```
$("#body").val('<%= @letter.body %>');
```

The code above works when `@letter.body` is just simple text, but it fails when there's newlines or anything else fancy in that field. How can I get the whole paragraph to render properly in my textarea, including any newlines, bullets, etc that might be included?

Comment: Fails how? JavaScript error or the newlines don't show up?

Comment: @alex - the code doesn't function if there are any `\n` characters (the JavaScript fails). I'm sure it fails with other special characters too but I have isolated the `\n` so far.

Comment: Is there an error reported in the console?

Comment: @alex - unfortunately not. The `.js.erb` file simply doesn't do anything. If I test an identical file with no newline, it works. Nothing in the console.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `\n` in a string would cause an issue when used like that.

Comment: @alex, it's a basics of js -- see it's string vars. And as I understand there are not normal escaped "\n" there, but raw \n chars.

Comment: Try double quotes around the erb substitution perhaps?

Comment: @jaydel - no difference there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3.0:

```
$("#body").val(<%= @letter.body.to_json %>);
```

Rails 3.1:

```
$("#body").val(<%= j @letter.body %>);
```

Comment: Sam - now I'm getting `&quot;This is my letter&quot;`. How do I get rid of the quotes for the textarea?

Comment: Nevermind - I just did a `gsub` and that makes the text appear in the textarea correctly. Thank you Sam!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP it could be as:

```
$("#body").val('<?=json_encode($letter->body)?>');
```

So find same json encode in ruby and you are done.

We need json encode as in js we can't have such var:

```
var f = 'daadsasd
asdadsdasdas';
```

only:

```
var f = 'daadsasd\nasdadsdasdas';
```

See:

- [How to do Ruby object serialization using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684588/how-to-do-ruby-object-serialization-using-json)
- http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/

Comment: Thanks for your answer gaRex - I'm getting `&quot;`s around my textarea value now. Any idea on how to get of them?

Comment: I just posted the quotes answer in a comment to Sam. Thanks for this answer gaRex. +1